# Powershell Error "The term 'Get-SPWeb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function..."

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, powershell-2.0

I just typed the follow to try and get my SharePoint site:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://nycs00058260/sites/usitp"
```

It gave me the following error

> The term 'Get-SPWeb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script...

The url is correct so why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I think this need to be run from the Management Shell rather than the console, it sounds like the module isn't being imported into the Powershell console.  You can add the module by running:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
```

in the Powershell console.

Comment: Great! This allow us to use Windows PowerShell ISE for SharePoint related stuff, which is much better as it support multi-line functions and has syntax validation!

Comment: Hi, I am getting error while running the mentioned command. Please check this error:Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 4.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand

Comment: @HarshaVardhini I am getting the same error but for PowerShell version 5. Did you figure out the problem?

Answer (score 10):

Run this script from SharePoint 2010 Management Shell as Administrator.

Comment: hi, I have a small question, how to check if the file already exists in sharepoint lib?

Comment: if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorActionSilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `Windows PowerShell`, find the item in the Start Menu called `SharePoint 2013 Management Shell`:

[image]