# PowerShell - read SharePoint file properties (datemodified, etc)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I need to compare a file in SharePoint against a local file and to make sure they are the same version (it's an accdb that's developed offline and shared in multiple client SharePoint locations). I need to get the modified date from the file in SharePoint, and I've been unable to do so.

*NB:* I don't have Get-SPWeb available, as this needs to be run by various users who won't have SharePoint 2013 Management Shell available to them ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122585/powershell-error-the-term-get-spweb-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet)).

I've tried using Get-PnPFile with -AsListItem, and it doesn't return an error but I can't access any properties.

I've tried .FieldValuesAsText and .ListItemAllFields and not getting anywhere.

This bit, connecting to the SharePoint resource via SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline, is working:

```
$SiteURL = "https://myorg.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite"
$FileRelativeURL = "Shared Documents/mydb.accdb"
$UserName = "user@myorg.org"
$PlainPassword = "myP@ssw0rd#"
$SecurePassword = $PlainPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $SecurePassword
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred
```

I tried this, and it downloads the file; I don't need to do that:

```
$file1 = Get-PnPFile -Url $FileRelativeURL -AsFile
```

According to [this](http://From%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps), "-AsListItem" returns the file as a listitem showing all its properties. So I tried it. It didn't download the file, and it didn't return an error, so maybe I have an object I can query now?

```
$file1 = Get-PnPFile -Url $FileRelativeURL -AsListItem
write-host $file1
```

The second line returns `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem`.

The following return empty strings:

```
write-host $file1.Name
write-host $file1.TimeLastModified
write-host $file1.LastModified
write-host $file1[-1]
write-host $file1[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Found FieldValuesAsText mentioned somewhere, so I tried it:

```
$props = $file1.FieldValuesAsText
write-host $props
write-host $props[0]
```

The first one returns `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldStringValues`; the second one returns an empty string.

Tried ListItemAllFields:

```
$props = $file1.ListItemAllFields
write-host $props
write-host $props[0]
```

The first line didn't generate an error; the second line returned an empty string; the third line returned:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:1
+ write-host $props[0]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Very new to PowerShell, and I'm probably missing something obvious. (SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline is installed and working.)

The code above doesn't include getting information from my local file; I haven't gotten that far yet. I imagine the instructions [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5878/getting-started-with-powershell-file-properties-and-methods/) will work. My issue is getting the metadata from the file in SharePoint.

Grateful for any assistance or pointing me to the right resource; I've done a couple hours of research and am coming up empty.

Comment: Additionally tried `$file1 | Get-Member` after reading this: https://www.codykonior.com/2013/03/26/powershell-how-to-show-all-of-an-objects-properties-and-values/. I got a _lot_ of output. But don't know what to do with it. None of the output says, "This is the ModifiedDate." :-)

Comment: I think your best bet would be to map the SharePoint location to a `PSDrive` according to [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/829dfd78-7737-4f95-84b0-ed6acaff4932/how-to-get-the-uploaded-documents-last-modified-date?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy) by using `New-PSDrive`. After that you can easily access it as a normal file system and consult the `LastWriteTime` property.

Comment: And, _that_ would be why I can't find how to do this documented anywhere. Thanks for this. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it. Or perhaps I should delete the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to map the SharePoint drive as a `PSDrive` on your system. Then you can treat it like a regular file system and the property `LastWriteTime` will be available.

More info on `New-PSDrive` can be found in the [documentation online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-6) or by typing `Get-Help New-PSDrive` in a PowerShell console/ISE.