# Connecting SharePoint to PowerShell and unlisting users

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm working on a script to automatically create AD accounts. The script downloads list of users from SharePonit and searches for new one and creates in AD. I have a few questions:

1. How can I list users from SP in PowerShell?
2. how to retrieve value data from SP e.g. Name, Surname

I must admit that I would like to start by listing the users.

The `Get-SPUser` command does not work. I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122585/powershell-error-the-term-get-spweb-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet) to this problem, but it did not help. In PS I'm a beginner, in programming I have experience.

Answer (score 0):

The command `Get-SPUser` would the user accounts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spuser?view=sharepoint-ps

In which server did you run the command? You need to run the `Get-SPUser` command in your sharepoint server.